# I followed blender guru's tutorial and I can't see the textures on my wall

Tags: texturing

[image]

It shows up perfectly in the preview but doesn't show up on my wall.

Here's my node setup:
[image]

Comment: You probably need to UV unwrap the wall. Select it in edit mode, then press U (unwrap) and select "Unwrap" (you should be able to get away with just that because it's just a flat plane)

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot!